# Printing Numbered Associative Array from MySQLi query in a Loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, mysqli

I had an averaged MySQL data invoked through `$conn -> query` method. I fetched the data through an associative array in `mysqli_fetch_assoc`. Which resulted that the data had the following format `Array ( [AVG(jwb1)] => 5 [AVG(jwb2)] => 5 [AVG(jwb3)] => 4.666666666666667)` with `AVG[jwb1]` as key.

I want to visualize all the data in an HTML Table using a loop. The problem is:

1. How to loop through the key (I guess it need a `for` loop) so it will call the value on the right row?
2. I want to round the decimal into 2 precision. Where should I put the `round()` command?

I've tried the following code:

```
//INVOKING RESULT

$nilai = $conn->query("SELECT AVG(jwb1), AVG(jwb2), AVG(jwb3) from tb_transaksi_jwb where id_mk= '$id_mk'");

//INSERTING VALUE TO ROWS BY FOR/WHILE LOOP

<?php

//looping assoc array

while ($rownilai = mysqli_fetch_assoc($nilai)) {
    for($no = 0; $no<8; $no++){
?>

<tr>
   <td>Soal <?= $no; ?></td>
   <td><?= $rownilai['AVG(jwb$no)']; ?></td>
   // I intended to get result of each $rownilai['AVG(jwb1)'],
   // $rownilai['AVG(jwb2)'] etc
</tr>

<?php
      }
   }
?>
```

But giving `undefined index` error. The intended result:

```
----------------------------
|Key            |Value     |
----------------------------
|AVGJwb1        |5         |
|AVGJwb2        |4,6       |
|AVGJwb3        |5         |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give alias to all average columns and use that key to print the values. See below,

```
$nilai = $conn->query("SELECT AVG(jwb1) AS jwb1_avg, AVG(jwb2) AS jwb2_avg, AVG(jwb3) AS jwb3_avg from tb_transaksi_jwb where id_mk= '$id_mk'");
```

Then you can print like `<?= $rownilai['jwb1_avg']; ?>`, `<?= $rownilai['jwb2_avg']; ?>`, `<?= $rownilai['jwb3_avg']; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the two parts of the array keyname together using the dot operator so replace the line
`<td><?= rownilai['AVG(jwb$no)']; ?></td>`

with

`<td><?= round($rownilai['AVG(jwb.$no)'],2); ?></td>`

which also performs the rounding to 2 decimal places